# Magento "Notice: Undefined variable: response"

Tags: php, magento

I'm running Magento 1.6.2.0.

I noticed in system.log every time an order is placed these 3 lines:

```
2012-12-19T15:37:00+00:00 ERR (3): Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::__construct() must be an instance of Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract, array given, called in /chroot/home/saucench/saucencheese.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php on line 1351 and defined  in /chroot/home/saucench/saucencheese.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php on line 138

2012-12-19T15:37:00+00:00 ERR (3): Recoverable Error: Argument 2 passed to Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::__construct() must be an instance of Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract, none given, called in /chroot/home/saucench/saucencheese.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php on line 1351 and defined  in /chroot/home/saucench/saucencheese.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php on line 138

2012-12-19T15:37:00+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: response  in /chroot/home/saucench/saucencheese.com/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php on line 141
```

So apparently the variable "response" isn't defined. Would anyone be able to help me locate the source that's causing this error? It can't be in the Config.php or Action.php since I've never modified those.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's on this file

```
/chroot/home/saucench/saucencheese.com/.../Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php 

on line 141
```

See what is happening there and make sure the `$variables` are defined.

Comment: This is the function:     
    Line 138: public function __construct(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request, Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract $response, array $invokeArgs = array())
   139: {
   140:     $this->_request = $request;
   141:     $this->_response= $response;
   142:  
   143:     Mage::app()->getFrontController()->setAction($this);
   144:
   145:     $this->_construct();
   146: }

Again the problem isn't in this file, it's in something that calls the __construct() function and passes it something that results an error. I'm trying to figure out what it's being passed.

Comment: Okay it looks like `$response` isn't being passed into the constructor. That's where the other errors come into play that you have above.

Comment: Or $response in an invalid `Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract` object? Since this script gets called every the site is loaded. So it must be only by an order that something invalid gets passed as a `Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract` object. The question is how can I track what calls this `__construct` function?

Comment: Inside that construct you can place: `$e = new Exception;
var_dump($e->getTraceAsString()); die();` and it will give you a stack trace of what was called by what.

Comment: Thanks I'll try it out when I get a chance, and let you know if it helped solve the error.

Comment: Ok, I've captured the trace and posted the result here [link](http://paste2.org/p/2660719). It still doesn't help me find _what_ is actually causing the error. It's possibly some data that gets sent by checkout that is faulty... but I can't figure out what it is.